# Adivinar el número con variables de sesión PHP

Tags: php, variables

estoy intentando hacer que al escribir un número entre 1 y 9999, me diga si es correcto o no, pero no consigo hacerlo, os paso el código por si veis el fallo ya que no entiendo del todo las variables de sesión.
También tengo que sacar el número de intentos, que imagino que se hará con un for incrementando la variable, pero no quiero avanzar con eso hasta sacar si el número es correcto o no.

Archivo Adiv.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Adivina el número</title>    
</head>
<body>
<h1>Adivina el número</h1>
    <echo>Este juego trata de adivinar un número aleatorio entre 1 y 9999.</echo><br/>
    <echo>Escribe un valor que esté entre estos 2 valores y prueba suerte.</echo>
<?
srand(time());
$numero = rand(1, 9999);
if ($_REQUEST['num'] == $numero){
 echo "Has acertado";
} else {
  echo "Prueba otra vez";
}
?>
<form action="Adiv_Num.php" method="get">
<input type="number" name="numero">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Probar suerte">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo Adiv_Num.php

```
<?
session_start();
// Inicio de sesiones.
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adivina el número</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
// Se verifica que exista la variable de sesión con nuestro numero aleatorio generado.
if (isset($_SESSION['num'])){
   // Si existe nuestro numero, empezamos a compararlo con lo que ingresaron por el formulario.
   if ($_SESSION['num'] == $_GET['numero']){
      echo "Has acertado";
      // Si se acierta, se borra el campo para volver a empezar.
   }
      unset ($_SESSION['num']);
      else {
     // Si no existe o se acierta, se prueba otra vez.
     echo "Prueba otra vez";
      }
   srand(time()); 
   // Devuelve un numero entre el 1 y el 9999.
   $_SESSION['num'] = rand(1, 9999);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que sacar la variable de sesion afuera del `if` asi:

```
<?
session_start();
// Inicio de sesiones.
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adivina el número</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
srand(time()); 
   // Devuelve un numero entre el 1 y el 9999.
   $_SESSION['num'] = rand(1, 9999);
// Se verifica que exista la variable de sesión con nuestro numero aleatorio generado.
if (isset($_SESSION['num'])){
   // Si existe nuestro numero, empezamos a compararlo con lo que ingresaron por el formulario.
   if ($_SESSION['num'] == $_GET['numero']){
      echo "Has acertado";
      // Si se acierta, se borra el campo para volver a empezar.
   }
      unset ($_SESSION['num']);
      else {
     // Si no existe o se acierta, se prueba otra vez.
     echo "Prueba otra vez";
      }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero nada, el problema es que al pasar al segundo archivo cuando lo envío no me sale nada de información de si está bien o mal, aunque si que me coge los valores de número y envío del GET.

Comment: puedes utilizar un var_dump($_SESSION['num']) de ese get para comprobar que valor tiene

Comment: No sale nada, así que imagino que no está cogiendo el valor de la variable.